# Can't pre-populate Room database and see it on RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-room

I am trying to develop an application that uses Room Persistence Database and displays a list on a RecyclerView, I've followed Google's tutorials and everything but I can seem to see the items on the screen, the app doesn't crash or anything just nothing appearing on the scree:

Here is the Data object class:

```
@Entity(tableName = "region")
public class Region {
@NonNull
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
private int mId;

@ColumnInfo(name = "region_name")
private String mRegionName;

@ColumnInfo(name = "association")
private String mAssociation;

@ColumnInfo(name = "season")
private String mSeason;

public Region(@NonNull int id, String regionName, String association, String season) {
    mId = id;
    mRegionName = regionName;
    mAssociation = association;
    mSeason = season;
}


@NonNull
public int getId() {
    return mId;
}

public void setId(@NonNull int id) {
    mId = id;
}

public String getRegionName() {
    return mRegionName;
}

public void setRegionName(String regionName) {
    mRegionName = regionName;
}

public String getAssociation() {
    return mAssociation;
}

public void setAssociation(String association) {
    mAssociation = association;
}

public String getSeason() {
    return mSeason;
}

public void setSeason(String season) {
    mSeason = season;
}
```

Here is the Data Dao:

```
@Dao
public interface RegionDao {
@Query("SELECT * FROM region")
List<Region> getAll();

@Insert
void insert(Region... region);

@Query("DELETE FROM region")
void deleteAll();
```

Here is the Adapter Class:

```
public class RegionsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RegionsAdapter.RegionViewHolder> {
private List<Region> mRegionList;
private Context mContext;
private int mRowLayout;
private RecyclerViewClickListener mListener;

public static class RegionViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    LinearLayout regionLayout;
    TextView regionName, regionAss, regionSeason;

    public RegionViewHolder(View v, RecyclerViewClickListener listener){
        super(v);
        regionLayout = v.findViewById(R.id.region_layout);
        regionName = v.findViewById(R.id.region_name);
        regionAss = v.findViewById(R.id.region_ass);
        regionSeason = v.findViewById(R.id.region_season);
    }
}

public void setClickListener(RecyclerViewClickListener recyclerViewClickListener){
    mListener = recyclerViewClickListener;
}

public RegionsAdapter(List<Region> regionList, Context context, int rowLayout, RecyclerViewClickListener listener) {
    mRegionList = regionList;
    mContext = context;
    mRowLayout = rowLayout;
    mListener = listener;
}

@Override
public RegionsAdapter.RegionViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                                  int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(mRowLayout, parent, false);
    final RegionsAdapter.RegionViewHolder holder = new RegionsAdapter.RegionViewHolder(view, mListener);
    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mListener.onClick(v,holder.getLayoutPosition());
        }
    });
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RegionViewHolder holder, final int position){
    holder.regionName.setText(mRegionList.get(position).getRegionName());
    holder.regionSeason.setText(mRegionList.get(position).getSeason());
    holder.regionAss.setText(mRegionList.get(position).getAssociation());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return mRegionList.size();
}
```

And this is the fragment that it is supposed to show the data base on:

```
public class RegionFragment extends Fragment {

private List<Region> mRegionList;
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.region_fragment, container, false);
    //whenever the activity is started, it reads data from database and stores it into
    // local array list 'mRegionList'
    final AppDatabase db = Room.databaseBuilder(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
            AppDatabase.class,"app_database").allowMainThreadQueries().build();
    List<Region> regionList = db.getRegionDao().getAll();
    // Initializing the RecyclerView
    mRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.region_rv);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext()));
    RegionsAdapter adapter = new RegionsAdapter(regionList, getActivity().
            getApplicationContext(), R.id.region_layout, new RecyclerViewClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view, int position) {
            // Handling what happenes when a card is clicked
            // TODO handling
        }
    });
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    return view;
}
```

This is the AppDatabase Class:

```
@Database(entities = {Region.class}, version = 1)
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

public abstract RegionDao getRegionDao();

private static AppDatabase sInstance;

static AppDatabase getDatabase(final Context context) {
    if (sInstance == null) {
        synchronized (AppDatabase.class){
        if (sInstance == null) {
            sInstance = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase.class,
                    "database").addCallback(sRoomDatabaseCallback).build();
        }
        }
    }
    return sInstance;
}




private static RoomDatabase.Callback sRoomDatabaseCallback =
        new RoomDatabase.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onOpen(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
                super.onOpen(db);
                new PopulateDbAsync(sInstance).execute();
            }
        };
```

And finally the AsyncClass to pre populate the database:

```
class PopulateDbAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

private final RegionDao mDao;

PopulateDbAsync(AppDatabase db) {
    mDao = db.getRegionDao();
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(final Void... params) {
    mDao.deleteAll();
    Region region = new Region(0,"Europe","UEFA","2017/2018");
    mDao.insert(region);
    region = new Region(1, "Americas","CONCACAF","2017/2018");
    mDao.insert(region);
    region = new Region(2, "Asia","AFC","2017/2018");
    mDao.insert(region);
    region = new Region(3, "International","FIFA","2017/2018");
    mDao.insert(region);
    region = new Region(4, "Other","ConIFA","2017/2018");
    mDao.insert(region);
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Just a tip, but you probably want to clear your question a bit and keep only the important parts of your code, there is way too much to be honest it's more likely that people won't read the whole thing as it would take them too much time. Visit the [ask] page and use this link to learn how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

if your id is `PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)`, then don't set id in constructor.

update your `onCreateView` , you are use wrong database.

```
 final AppDatabase db =AppDatabase.getDatabase(getActivity());
List<Region> regionList = db.getRegionDao().getAll();// here you have fire your query in background thread. you can search for that
```